# Mount SMB / New-PSDrive (PowerShell on macOS)

Tags: macos, powershell, mount, smb

Our computing environment is primarily windows, but I work mostly from macOS. Typically, I `enter-pssession` to a windows server/workstation using `-SSHTransport` and am able to make use of any fileshares mapped to that particular machine. In lieu of always being connected to a different workstation, I'm trying to somehow mount fileshares by way of `New-PSDrive` or somehow otherwise navigate fileshares using powershell so that I can access files and resources across the network. Since I'm primarily writing scripts for later use, I don't want to depend on manually mounting an SMB share via finder and then `set-location` to `/volumes/ShareName`. I've had a lot of trouble finding documentation or resources online to help walk me through this process. As far as I can tell, PowerShell on macOS also doesn't support the use of UNC paths. Is there any known work around or strategy for using an SMB share as a 'psdrive' or accessing those fileshares via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell core running on linux/macOS doesn't really have any special tools for SMB outside of what the the local bash shell provides. It relies on the OS filesystem and tools to mount and browse network files, so you would mount your share the same way as if you weren't running powershell.

The main ways to do that on MAC are probably either `mount_smbfs`:

```
mount_smbfs //user@server.domain.com/share ./share
```

Or via Finder like you mentioned:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" mount volume "smb://server.domain.com/share"'
```

Both of these commands should run fine from powershell

---

If you get prompted for your password for each share, then look into your kerberos settings (Assuming your mac is joined to the windows domain). I believe it's usually automatic, but you can manually create/update your token for your current user with `kinit`.

Comment: I realize that my response is seriously delayed, but your answer was particularly helpful. This let me modify my scripts to mount the share's natively and not have to SSH in to a windows machine. Thank you so much!